# NGINX + Node.js res.redirect('../Path')

Tags: node.js, redirect, nginx

I have node app that does the following

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('../Path');
});

app.get('/Path, function(req, res){
    res.render('page');
});
```

going to `<servername>:<port>/` redirects to `<servername>:<port>/Path` and page loads

This works fine. Now I'm adding NGINX to the equation and I want all my node path under the location Location1 so I have this in NGINX:

```
location /Location1/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:port/
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

That works fine if I go directly to `<servername>/Location1/Path` but does not work if I try to go to `<servername>/Location1` it redirects to `<servername>/Path1`

I thought the `../Path` in the redirect is for relative urls but apparently it does not work in this case. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone runs into this issue in the future, I changed the redirect and it works with both NGINX and without. Removing the '../' from the redirect let the url change while keeping the reverse proxy location.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('Path');
});
```